# The length of Benoa bay of Bali island

Tags: data, indonesia

Since Indonesia's spatial data infrastructure is terrible, how can I know the length in a kilometre of Benoa bay of Bali island, Indonesia?

I tried to google it and shockingly I didn't get any information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t blame the system, Indonesia SDI is good enough. It’s just a matter of skill from the user, to utilize existing information.

You can download the admin boundary of Bali, convert it to polyline, and delete other feature except the bay area, then calculate the length. As simple as that.